# Let $A ,B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^{k}$ and $A+B =\{a+b \mid a\in A, b\in B\}$then:

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $A ,B \subseteq \Bbb{R}^k$ and $A+B =\{a+b \mid a\in A,  b\in B\}$then:

a)If $A,B$ be open then $A+B =\{a+b \mid a\in A,  b\in B\}$ is open.
b)If $A,B$ be connect then $A+B$ is connect?
c)If $A,B$ be bounded then $A+B$ is bounded?
d)If $A,B$ be compact then $A+B$ is compact?

I think for a) we can write $A+B=\bigcup _{b\in B} (A+b)$ and every $(A+b)$ is open and union of every arbitary open sets are open then $A+B$ is open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) OK with your proof.

b) Yes. A product of two (non empty) connected sets is a connected set and the image of a connected set by a continuous map is connected.

c) Yes. By triangular inequality.

d) Yes. The image of a compact set by a continuous map is compact and the product of two compact sets is compact.

Comment: $A+b$ is the translated by $b$ of open set $A$ which is open because a translation is an open map. b) I precised in the answer that the two singletons have to be distinct. d) The map $(x,y) \to x+y$ is continuous and $A \times B$ is compact as a product of compacts. And I imagine that you know that the image of a compact by a continuous map is compact.

Comment: You're right for b). My mistake.

Comment: For b) if  $A=empty$ and $B=non empty$ then $A+B =B$?

Comment: I would say that $A+B=\emptyset$ when $A=\emptyset$. If $A=\emptyset$, $A \times B=\emptyset$ and $f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ for any application.

Comment: @amirbahadory Wiki says about _Minkowski addition_: "for every subset, S, of a vector space, its sum with the empty set is empty: $S + \varnothing = \varnothing$"

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net 
I think you are mistaken when you think that the sum of the sets is the same thing that the product of the sets. This error does not give you the right to use the theorems that are valid for the product sets. For example, the product of two disconnected sets will always be disconnected set, but the sum of two disconnected sets may be connected set.

Comment: @grizzly Denote by $f$ the application $f: \mathbb{R}^k \times \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^k$ defined by $f(x,y)=x+y$. $f$ is continuous and $A+B$ is the image by $f$ of $A \times B$. Then I use well known theorems on continuous functions.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Of course, you are right! It is my mistake. Thank you for the explanation. Sorry.